# How to perform javascript only when the page is first loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to perform javascript only when the page is first loaded? I need to make a function that does not run again reloading the page! Can anyone help?

Comment: You won't be able to tell a difference between a page being reloaded and a page being visited for the first time. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You could set a cookie.

Comment: You could use localStorage and set a flag for it

Comment: How do you define *first time*?

Comment: Okay, I figured even if I could not do that. So do we have to call a javascript function by JAVA?

Comment: If the localStorage.firstTime is not defined then is the first time o.o

Comment: I define first team to load the page once and when reloading javascript should not be executed.

Comment: yep check if localStorage.something has a value if not set it and run your script the next time localStorage.something will have a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming localStorage is supported in the browser being used:

```
if (! localStorage.getItem("beenHere")) {
    localStorage.setItem("beenHere", true);

    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `cookie` on the client's browser.

```
$(function() {
    if (!$.cookie("page-viewed")) {
        // call your code

        $.cookie("page-viewed", true);
    }
});
```

`Cookies` are supported and enabled 99% of the time.

Comment: Note that `$.cookie` requires a plugin and is *not* part of the jQuery core.

Answer (score 0):

You should store information about your past visit somewhere. The simplest solution to store it server side and pass it to the client. If you are working without backend you could use cookie or localStorage to store info between requests.

Answer (score 0):

Just from the others responses but without Jquery or very new technologies:

```
var myFunc = function() { alert("Hello World"); };
window.onload = function() {
    var firstTime = getCookie("firstTime");
    if (firstTime === null) {
        document.cookie="firstTime=Nope";
        myFunc();
    } else alert("Already seen");
};

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
       if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```